# How do I set a file to non-hidden with batch?

Tags: batch-file, attributes, hidden

I'm trying to edit the attribute of a file to non-hidden in a batch script. I have no luck so far, can someone help me with a code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use the command
`attrib -H <filename>` in your batch script.

Ref: http://www.easydos.com/attrib.html

Answer (score 0):

`attrib -h myfile.txt`
or
`attrib -h "c:\filepath\Myfile.txt"`

For more information:
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490868.aspx

Answer (score 0):

```
attrib -h #filenamehere#.txt
```

replace #filenamehere# with the path to the file